# Why we actually use Open and Release in a kernel module programming ? what is the calling pattern of these module?

Tags: linux, module, kernel, driver, device

Why we actually use Open and Release in a kernel module programming ? what is the calling pattern of these module ?
I have read the kernel module programming book. and i cant able to clear these doubts. i get to know the File_Operation and IOCTL Functionality but Release and Open are not understanding. kindly help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Method is a device driver implemented to do initialization for later tasks.
Which performs mainly the following tasks: 
1. Check the device is ready / any hardware problems.
2. Initialize the device if opened for first time.
3. allocate and fill data structure.
in this case we have open a file data for device driver. the calling is done similar way Open a file. when we open a file with specific device name. this method will be executed.

Release Method:
which is just reverse of Open Method.